# How to load data from multiple files to multiple tables?

Tags: ssis

Suppose we have 10 different files, which need to be loaded into 10 different tables. Table names should be same as the file names. Suggest some efficient way to load all the files at once using SSIS package?

Comment: Define efficient.  Do you want a process that is effecient for your developers or a process that efficiently moves the data through the pipeline into the database?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create SSIS Package.
2. Create 10 Flat File connections (For Each File).
3. Create 10 Dataflow objects in each:

   - Flat File Source (selected txt file)
   - Data Conversion element
   - Derived Columns element
   - Ole DB destination element ( in this element you need to push button "New" near the table selection combox. SSIS gonna give you SQL query with table creation code. There will be all columns from your File, also edit table Name)

Before inserting tables, create SQL Task to truncate these tables.
You need probably edit some data types, because almost always SSIS offer string type -varchar.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved easily in SSIS using BCP Command, Two SQL Tasks and one Foreach container.

Create table Schema in database for respective flat files.

Now create a new table(Path_Table) in database, The table should have three columns as shown below.

Column 1: Table_name        Column 2:File_path  Column 3:File_name

Example to insert data in (Path_Table)

```
Insert into Path_Table Values (‘dept_table’,’d:\\’,’department.txt’)
```

It works out for ‘n’ number of tables.

After this open SSDT create a new SSIS package.Now drag “Execute SQL Task”

Create a new variable of name “tbl_variable” of data type object.

Now Edit “Execute SQL Task” and in general tab make OLE DB connection and write below query in SQL Statement tab.

*// Select Table_name,File_path,File_name from dbo.Path_table  //*

Now in SQL Task change Result Set property to “Full result set”

In left pane of “Execute SQL Task” select “Result Set” map result of the query to our variable(tbl_variable) .

Now drag and drop “for each container”. In the left pane select “collection” in that select “Enumerator” as “For Each ADO Enumerator”  from drop down list and then select variable(tbl_variable) for ADO object source variable. Lastly select “Enumeration Mode” as “Rows in first Table”.

That ‘tbl_variable’ result has three columns. Now in “Variable Mappings” pane map three column results to three new variables (data type is varchar) i.e tbl_name, file_path, and  file_name with the index number as (0,1,2) respectively as it would be a parameter mapping for next SQL Task(Load Data)
Now inside “For each container” take a “SQL task” . In “SQL command”
Write query as:

```
declare @tblname sysname=?
declare @dir varchar(500)=?
declare @file_name varchar(500)=?
declare @SQLstring  varchar(2000)
set @SQLstring='BCP AdventureWorks2012.'+@tblname+'  IN  '+@dir+'\'+@file_name+'.txt  -c  -t, -S PRINHYLTPDL0937 -T  -R'
exec xp_cmdshell @SQLstring
go
```

In the above query make changes of database and other as per your requirement.
In “SQL task” in parameter mapping pane, Map previous created three variable (tbl_name, file_path, and file_name) results as input to the above query with Parameter Name as 0,1 and 2 repectively.